# Pushing string into an empty array with FOR Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop

The goal is to input a string "Item" into myArray with the function and input it the number of times that I indicate in the function arrayFiller parameter. Here's what I have so far. I am still new to FOR loops so I'm not sure what to put into the next two parameters in the FOR loop. I'm guessing that I will need to use the .push object at some point but I've been trying this particular problem for so long.

```
myArray = [];

function arrayFiller(times) {
 for (i = 0;     ;i++)
 myArray.push[i];
}

arrayFiller(2);
```

arrayFiller(5) should add five different strings of "Item" in the empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `.push` is a method, so you need to use `(` and `)` to pass it the
  value to push into the array, not `[` and `]`.
- You didn't configure your loop to have a looping condition.
- You never wrote any code to inspect the array after the
  operation to know if it worked.
- Your code simply inserts the looping counter value into the array. If
  you want something else (like "item"), you'd have to add that.

```js
myArray = [];

function arrayFiller(times, item) {
 for (i = 0; i < times; i++)
 myArray.push("Item");
}

arrayFiller(5);
console.log("# of items in array: " + myArray.length, myArray);

myArray.length = 0; // Reset array

arrayFiller(2);
console.log("# of items in array: " + myArray.length, myArray);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Scott! Could you explain how I would change the numbers showing up in the new array to be a number of strings instead? So that instead of numbers it is listing "item"?

Comment: @Galwayshannon I don't understand. My code shows how you could insert a string like "item". But I don't know what you mean by "number of strings". Are you saying you just want to be able to know how many items there are in the array?

Comment: No. Sorry. I need to push "item" into the empty array as many times as I indicate in the function parameter.

Comment: @Galwayshannon That's exactly what my code does. Have you run my code snippet? If you don't also want to see the number just don't concatenate `i` onto the end of it.